# How use set method on model Backbone to change a data?

Tags: backbone.js, ipython

I'm new with Backbone and I think I misunderstand the use of get/set with the model. I made a really simple example with IPython widget :

```
class Automaton(widgets.DOMWidget):
    from IPython.display import Javascript

    _view_name = traitlets.Unicode('AutomatonView', sync=True)
    nodes = traitlets.List(sync=True)

%%javascript
require(['widgets/js/widget'], function(WidgetManager){
    var AutomatonView = IPython.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        render: function(){

            var n_nodes = this.model.get("nodes").slice();
            n_nodes[0] += 1;
            this.model.set("nodes", n_nodes);
            return this;
        },

    });
    WidgetManager.register_widget_view("AutomatonView", AutomatonView);
});
```

So now I can call the widget like that:

```
a = Automaton(nodes=[1])
```

What I understand here is: nodes is passed to the model and now in the model nodes = [1], then I create a new node [2] that I'm setting to the model, so I'm expected for the nodes value be [2] now, but If I ask

```
a.nodes
```

It's say:

```
[1]
```

Sorry if I don't understand something really basic, if you can explain whats is happening here it will be really useful for me. I checked if the n nodes is [2] with a console log and it's fine so it's really with "this.model.set" the problem.

Comment: Why are you calling a `slice` method there?

Comment: The slice method is just to copy the current data, I could not use this and just set something into the model.set, but my example is a part of a biggest program that's why I let the slice here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're rendering the view? Try to put this code into an `initialize` method instead, and everything should work just fine. By the way, this should work even without a `set` method call:

```
initialize: function() {
    var n_nodes = this.model.get("nodes");
    n_nodes[0] += 1;
    return this;
},
```

Comment: I fixed it with this.touch();

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that can help someone but I fixed my error with adding

```
this.touch();
```

I found my answer on this example : http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Interactive%20Widgets/Custom%20Widgets.ipynb

> " it is very important that we call this.touch() to let the widget machinery know which view changed the model "